# Issues with dependencies for Talkie Pie workaround

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm setting up a simple intercom system with Raspberry Pi Zero W's as server and clients.

I'm following installation guides for:
https://github.com/dchote/talkiepi
and have also looked in to
https://github.com/CustomMachines/talkiepi

Both refer to a workaround for Pi Zero that are included. Problem is that the workarounds depends on some older packages, getting error such as:

```html
 libopenal-dev : Depends: libopenal1 (= 1:1.17.2-4) but 1:1.19.1-1 is to be installed
```

Not sure how to proceed from here? Anyone can support?
/Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Just install the version it requires!

`sudo apt-get install libopenal1=1:1.17.2-4`